# Acabo de crear mi Api con C# y al poner new migration tengo este error

Tags: c#, api, controller, constructor

System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Action'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'object', 'method' in 'Action(object object, IntPtr method)'.